# Excel IF condition that will evaluate to TRUE if entered as an array formula, and FALSE if not

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I'm trying to fool-proof a dashboard that I'm handing off to someone else, and it contains some array formulas. If someone edits one of the array formulas and forgets to hit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, right now all that happens is the formula starts returning results that are incorrect in a subtle way.

What I would like is some sort of `IF` check I could add to the formula that will allow me to return a clear error if they forget to enter it as an array formula.

Something like:

```
=IF(IsArrayFormula, NormalFormula, "Ctrl+Shift+Enter Required")
```

VBA's not an option for me, although I won't down-vote if you want to leave a VBA solution for someone who doesn't have that restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MATCH in the criteria like this:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(MATCH({1,2},{2},0),0)),NormalFormula,"Ctrl+Shift+Enter Required")
```

If the formula is not entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter, then the match will only try to find `1` in the `{2,2}` array, which it will not find and return an error.

This error will then return `0` to the IF condition which will trigger the False condition.

If entered properly it will add the `0` from the error then find the `2` in the fist place and return the sum of `1` to the condition.

This will return True and the normal formula will fire.

---

Just because you opened it up to vba.

This will automatically turn the formula into an array formula if the user forgets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G25")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Target.HasArray Then
            Target.FormulaArray = Target.Formula
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course this can get complicated when ensuring that only the cells that should have array formulas in them get checked.  I only check G25.

Comment: You need to replace `NormalFormula` with an array formula, for now it is just a place holder.

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to be able to point NormalFormula to an actual cell.

Comment: No, the problem is the OP has an array formula in a cell, and sometimes the user forgets to hit CSE when exiting edit mode.  Some array formulas will return a value, albeit usually wrong.  So the OP asked for a formula method that would indicate whether the formula had been entered properly.

Comment: Now I understand. __This is an ingenious answer__. Perhaps a little more explanation would help the old cats like me. Have an upvote.

Comment: **This should have +50 by now**. It's easily the smartest Excel answer I've seen this year.

Comment: @Bathsheba done, but I've seen smarter......................................... (from the same author :D )

Comment: The condition could be also simplified to just `SUM(0+CHOOSE({1,2},0,1))` ?

Comment: @g.kov there are a myriad of ways, that is a good one and shorter.

Comment: Awesome. I figured once *a* solution was found some code golf would ensue. Regardless, I've been messing with attempts like this for a while and you actually found one that worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, I've inverted this condition just so it's easy to paste directly in front of any other formula (and have excel auto-insert the final closing bracket): `=IF(NOT(SUM(0+CHOOSE({1,2},0,1))),"Ctrl+Shift+Enter Required",`

Comment: Actually, since I'm after the inverted condition, it's simpler to change the math a little rather than use `NOT`:
`=IF(SUM(1*CHOOSE({1,2},-1,1)),"Error: Ctrl+Shift+Enter Required","s'good")`